# Two cells in single CollectionView of different dimensions

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have two cells within a single collection view. They both have different dimensions but for some reason on runtime both of the cells appear to have the same dimension.

Here's my setup:

```
internal func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if cellType == .books {
        return books.count
    } else if cellType == .spotlights {
        return spotlights.count
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}

internal func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if cellType == .books {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "booksCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! BooksCollectionCell
        let bookTitle = books[indexPath.item].title
        let authors = books[indexPath.item].authors
        cell.configureCell(title: bookTitle, authorNames: authors)
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "spotlightsCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! spotlightsCollectionViewCell
        cell.configureCell(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "testImage"))
        return cell
    }
}
```

Here's my storyboard screenshots:

[image]

and this is setup for collectionView:

[image]

edit: So I managed to get somwhere (thanks to cpatmulloy) by putting this code in cellForItem:

```
cell.frame = CGRect(x: cell.frame.origin.x, y: cell.frame.origin.y, width: 180.0, height: 130.0)
```

However, here's the result (look at the last cell in tableview):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try explicitly setting the cell's height and width in the cellForItemAtIndex Path function.

Be sure to set these example properties (i.e bookCellWidth) yourself

```
internal func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if cellType == .books {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "booksCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! BooksCollectionCell
            let bookTitle = books[indexPath.item].title
            let authors = books[indexPath.item].authors
            cell.configureCell(title: bookTitle, authorNames: authors)

            cell.frame = CGRect(x: cell.frame.origin.x, y: cell.frame.origin.y, width: bookCellWidth, height: bookCellHeight)

            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "spotlightsCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! spotlightsCollectionViewCell
            cell.configureCell(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "testImage"))

            cell.frame = CGRect(x: cell.frame.origin.x, y: cell.frame.origin.y, width: spotlightCellWidth, height: spotlightCellHeight)

            return cell
        }
    }
```

Comment: made a bit of a difference but now the cells are overlapping

Comment: Ok be sure that the properties bookCellHeight, bookCellWidt match the values you have in your "setup for collectionView" (the third image in your original post) for your bookCollectionView.

Comment: Also ensure that the properties spotlightCellHeight and spotlightCellWicth match the values of cell width and cell height  have for your setup of spotlightColletionView

Comment: seems like it's getting there but as i scroll to left/right the images are sort of... choppy...

Comment: I would look in to using UICollectionFlowLayout:https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewflowlayout. This provides better access to changing the layout of your collection views

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I managed to fix it!

First I added `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` to the `cell` class, then:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if cellType == .spotlights {
        return CGSize(width: 250.0, height: 180.0)
    } else {
        return (collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout).itemSize
    }
}
```